# Add up different slider values - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uislider, addition

My sliders are located on 10 different views. So, I want the user to be able to select a value with `ratingSliderOne`, and then move on to "Page 2" and select another value etc. Those values should then be added up to a total

.h

```
@interface CBViewController : UIViewController

//Scorelabel
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger theTotalScore;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *totalScoreLabel;

// Page 1
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSliderOne;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeaterLabelOne;

// Page 2
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSliderTwo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeaterLabelTwo;

// Page 3
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSliderThree;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeaterLabelThree;

// Page 4
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSliderFour;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeaterLabelFour;

// Page 5
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSliderFive;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeaterLabelFive;

// Page 6
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSliderSix;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeaterLabelSix;

// Page 7
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSliderSeven;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeaterLabelSeven;

// Page 8
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSliderEight;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeaterLabelEight;

// Page 9
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSliderNine;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeaterLabelNine;

// Page 10
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *ratingSliderTen;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repeaterLabelTen;


-(void)updateTotalScores;

- (IBAction)ratingSliderDidChange:(id)slider;

@end
```

.m

```
    - (IBAction)ratingSliderDidChange:(id)slider
{

    int sliderValue1 = self.ratingSliderOne.value;
    int sliderValue2 = self.ratingSliderTwo.value;

    int total = sliderValue1 + sliderValue2;

    self.theTotalScore = total;
    NSLog(@"%i, %i, %i", sliderValue1, sliderValue2, total);
    [self updateTotalScores];
}

-(void)updateTotalScores{



    if (_theTotalScore > 0) {
        self.totalScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _theTotalScore];
        NSLog(@"%i", _theTotalScore);
    }
}
```

Currently, the `NSLog(@"%i, %i, %i", sliderValue1, sliderValue2, total);` returns the correc values for each slider. But when you change from page 1 (i.e. ratingSliderOne) to page 2, it "forgets" the value of ratingSliderOne.

EDIT: Added all the code and clarified the question

Comment: theSlider.value is the current value.

Comment: I fixed it myself with this if statement:     
if (theSlider.value == theSlider.value) {
        int newValue = theSlider.value - theSlider.value;
        self.theTotalScore = newValue;
    }

Comment: @foffer `if (theSlider.value == theSlider.value)` will always be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`- (IBAction)ratingSliderDidChange:(id)slider` is a delegate callback. It will be fired every time it moves or any other slider connected on the screen moves.

it sounds like what you need is inside this callback to get the value of each slider on the page and create the total each time. Like so:

```
- (IBAction)ratingSliderDidChange:(id)slider
{
    int total = 0;

    total += self.ratingSliderOne.value;
    total += self.ratingSliderTwo.value;

    // etc ....

    self.theTotalScore = total;
    NSLog(@"%i", _theTotalScore);
    [self updateTotalScores];
}
```

Comment: your solution makes sense, but it doesn't seem to work. I't only returns the value for the current slider. I.e., when I change page to a new slider, it disregards the old value and only displays the new one.

Comment: @foffer it appears you haven't explained what your doing very well. How and where are you creating all of your sliders (edit your question with more details). What you are doing in your question is, you have a global, every time the slider changes you add a value to it. It sounds like now what you should be doing is having a variable for each slider and a total. When the user makes a change the total should be updated to the sum of all the other values and then update the label

Comment: My question was indeed a bit ambiguous, but it seems like you've caught on to what I want. So for not being able to clarify properly. I've tried your method, posting each value to a variable, and then adding them up in a variable in the end. The problem I've now got is that the slider value from page 1 isn't retained. If I NSLog ratingSliderOne.value, when I'm on page 2, it returns 0.

Comment: @foffer please post the code as to how you are trying to access this value and the structure of the app. It could be 1 of 100 different issues. Edit your question don't add it in a comment

Comment: I've posted the code now and cleaned up the question a bit

Comment: @foffer ok now i'm very confused, you said different pages? I assumed you meant different `UIViewController`'s. I'm guessing `CBViewController` is some third party code that displays multiple pages on the one screen. I have no idea what this is doing and I'm guessing its cleaning up the data when the page changes, meaning you can't access that data. If this is the case I would suggest having a property for each value, when the page changes store that sliders value in a property and on the didChange create an int for the total and add all the properties similar to the way I did it above.

Comment: Your answer eventually got me there Simon. Thank you very much for your help. Even though my question was a bit obscure!